# Postgres 9.3: How to update row that has max value of a timestamp in addition to other selection criteria?

Tags: postgresql

I want to allow users to cancel recurring subscriptions. The easiest way to do this given the other infrastructure I've got is to set the `recurring` field = 0 for the user's latest appointment (datewise). So I need to update the value of field `recurring` only in the row that matches a specific user's latest appointment.

Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE appointments SET recurring = 0 WHERE id = 433 AND time = max(time);


ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...ments set recurring = 0 where id = 433 and time = MAX(time);
```

and

```
 UPDATE appointments SET recurring = 0 WHERE id = 433 AND time = SELECT MAX(time) FROM appointments WHERE id = 433;
```

Here's the relevant part of the appointments table:

```
                                           Table "public.appointments"
      Column      |            Type             |                           Modifiers
------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer                     |
 time             | timestamp with time zone    |
 recurring        | integer                     |
```

Where should I go from here? Is it necessary to make this into a two part call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE appointments SET recurring = 0 
WHERE id = 433 
AND time = (select max(time) from appointments where id = 433);
```

... is the answer. You just needed brackets.

Comment: thanks that worked great. Can you tell me how I know when brackets are needed and when they're not? I'm newish to databases and I often find I have them when I shouldn't and vice versa. For example for an insert into...select there should be no brackets. What's the difference?

Comment: @Fawn: This one is a sub-select, which always requires parentheses. The [`INSERT` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) accepts a *query* as source in standard syntax. If in doubt, consult the [SQL command reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-commands.html).